# How can I name the text file I create after the current date/time

Tags: c++, datetime, time, text-files, time-t

First of all, my knowledge of X++ is minimal, I just need to edit the code I've been given.
I have a C++ program which creates a text file and stores data in it. Right now the program is using:

```
outfile.open("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/MATLAB/datafile.txt", std::ios::app);
```

But I need to change this code so each time i run this code, it will create a new file name. My suggestion is to somehow incorporate the time/date as the file name, but I am unsure how to do this. I've tried researching around, and it looks like using `time_t` is the way to go, but I'm unsure how to utilize it for my case.

Is it possible to save the time/date as a variable, then use:

```
outfile.open("C:/Users/td954/Documents/MATLAB/<DEFINED VARIABLE>", std::ios::app);
//                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

if so, how would I go about this?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code:

```
time_t currentTime = time(0);
tm* currentDate = localtime(&currentTime);
char filename[256] = {0};

strcpy(filename, "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/MATLAB/datafile");
strcat(filename, fmt("-%d-%d-%d@%d.%d.%d.txt",
       currentDate->tm_hour, currentDate->tm_min, currentDate->tm_sec,
       currentDate->tm_mday, currentDate->tm_mon+1,
       currentDate->tm_year+1900).c_str());

outfile.open(filename, std::ios::app);
```

tm* and time_t are in ctime header. fmt is just function like sprintf, which formats string. Implementation(not mine, found on stackoverflow IIRC):

```
#include <cstdarg>
std::string fmt(const std::string& fmt, ...) {
    int size = 200;
    std::string str;
    va_list ap;
    while (1) {
        str.resize(size);
        va_start(ap, fmt);
        int n = vsnprintf((char*)str.c_str(), size, fmt.c_str(), ap);
        va_end(ap);
        if (n > -1 && n < size) {
            str.resize(n);
            return str;
        }
        if (n > -1)
            size = n + 1;
        else
            size *= 2;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Ive tried implementing the code you suggested, but i get the error 'fmt': identifier not found. Is there a header i need to include for that function

Comment: Look at whole post... I've given you code of fmt. It's second code.

Comment: Just copy second code(fmt function definition), then put #include <ctime>, then under it put first code.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do something like this:

```
// Calculate the path
time_t current_time = time(nullptr);
std::ostringstream path_out(prefix);
path_out << "-" < < current_time << ".txt";
std::string path = path_out.str();

// Open a file with the specified path.
std::ofstream out(path.c_str(), std::ios::app);

// do stuff with "out"
```

That being said, if you are trying to use the time for the filename in order to create temporary files, then the solution you are looking for is likely platform-specific. On UNIX-based systems, [mkstemp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkstemp.html) is the preferred way to create temporary files (I'm not sure what the preferred way to do this is on Windows, but who cares ;)).

Comment: In the line:
std::ostringstream path_out(prefix);

what does prefix mean, im getting undefined identifier for it.

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you have a string variable named "prefix" that contains "C:\..." (replace "..." with the rest of that path).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timestamp provided through the date and time facilities of C++11. In particular, the `now()` function of the `std::chrono` namespace will return what you want:

```
#include <chrono>

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "myfile" << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << ".txt";
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

std::ofstream out(oss.str(), std::ios_base::app);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ctime>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>

std::string getTimestampedFilename(const std::string &basePathname) {
   std::ostringstream filename;
   filename << basePathname << '.' << static_cast<unsigned long>(::time(0));
   return filename.str();
}
```

Now, you can use this elsewhere...

```
template<class T>
void writeToFile(const std::string &basePathname, T data) {
    std::string filename = getTimestampedFilename(basePathname);
    std::ofstream outfile(filename.c_str());

    if (outfile) {
       outfile << data;
    }
    else {
       throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open '" + filename + "' for writing.");
    }
}
```

Comment: An added benefit of using this approach is that you're using a reusable function that clearly states what it's doing.  This should be a goal of any software that you write.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
std::time_t t = std::time(NULL);
std::tm *ptm = std::localtime(&t);
std::stringstream ss;
ss << ptm->tm_year+1900 << std::setw(2) << ptm->tm_mon+1 << ptm->tm_mday << ptm->tm_hour+1 << ptm->tm_min+1 << ptm->tm_sec+1;
outfile.open(("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/MATLAB/datafile_"+ss.str()+".txt").c_str(), std::ios::app);
```